# ThreeJS WebVR camera Settings

Tags: three.js, webvr

ThreeJS WebVR mode forgets the perspective camera near and far frustum plane settings. Hence parts of my objects get hidden. I wish to have a far frustum plane value of 10000 but when I enter VR mode my far frustum plane value is default to 1000. But this weirdness happens only in google chrome. When I use the Samsung internet browser and enter VR everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

VR mode uses 2 different cameras as opposed to the single camera in regular rendering mode.. I'm wondering if there is a bug in the state synchronization between the 2 when VR mode starts.. or maybe you're starting up the VR mode before the main camera state is initialized, and the VR cameras start up with a default state or something?

Comment: No, I'm starting VR mode after camera initialization.